# Bitwise operations in MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access, bitwise-and

I have a table which contains an answer. This answer is a combination of a set list of numbers. (see below)

Possible values

> 2
>   4
>   8
>   16
>   32
>   64

If I have the answer of Answer 24 – I need some method to work out the only values that could have been selected are 16 and 8.
I am told if this where SQL I would use a bitwise operation.

I am fairly advance in Access but tend not to use VBA code, but am open to all ideas.

Answer (score 8):

Compare [KB194206](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194206) (the gist of it: *"The Microsoft Jet database engine does not support bitwise operations in SQL. This behavior is by design."*), which basically means you're stuck with VBA.

And bitwise in VBA is very simple, because in VBA *all* locical operators are bitwise.

Just create a wrapper function:

```
Function BitAnd(Value1 As Long, Value2 As Long) As Long
    BitAnd = Value1 And Value2
End Function
```

and use it in your SQL

```
WHERE
    BitAnd([someColumn], 64) > 0
```

Do the same thing for the other bitwise operations you need.

---

You could use it in joins, as well. Assume you have an `FlagsTable (FlagValue, FlagName)` that contains the names for each of your available flags:

```
SELECT
  d.Id,
  d.BitField,
  f.FlagName
FROM
  DataTable d
  INNER JOIN FlagsTable f ON BitAnd(d.BitField, o.FlagValue) > 0
```

This query would be one way to address your *"24 consists of 16 and 8"* sub-question.

Comment: +1 for the clear and precise reply. But remember that such criteria will give slow performance with larger volumes !

Comment: @iDevlop That's almost always the consequence of using bit fields.