# Decode error code using sequence 1,2,4,8,16,32,64.124,etc. in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

To validate user input, I use different functions in Access VBA which all may produce error codes. The primary function creates a sum of all error codes and returns it to the requesting procedure. As error codes I used a binary sequence to create an unique return code (1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128, etc)
Can anyone help me with a simple piece of VBA code to decode the return code to see which errors occurred, for example provide all error codes in an array?
For example: error 274 is a result of 2, 16 and 256
Looked for hours, but anything I could find is written in another code like C#, Perl, etc. (which I were not able to change into VBA)
Thx!

Comment: [Bit Manipulations](http://functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson04.htm), [Bitwise operations in MS access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143813/bitwise-operations-in-ms-access),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a typical [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). Something like this will help you start:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngInput        As Long
    Dim lngTry          As Long
    Dim lngReduce       As Long: lngReduce = 10

    lngInput = 274

    While lngInput > 0
        lngTry = 2 ^ lngReduce
        lngReduce = lngReduce - 1
        If lngInput \ lngTry > 0 Then
            lngInput = lngInput - lngTry
            Debug.Print lngTry
        End If
    Wend

End Sub
```

You will get 256, 16, 2 printed in the console.

Answer (score 3):

I use this function to determine whether a flag enum has a given flag - seems applicable to your case:

```
Public Function HasFlag(ByVal value As Long, ByVal flag As Long) As Boolean
    HasFlag = (value And flag) = flag
End Function
```

It's basically a small abstraction over a little bitwise check.

That way you can define an enum with your custom error codes:

```
Public Enum CustomErrors
    ERR_None = 0
    ERR_Foo = 2 ^ 0
    ERR_Bar = 2 ^ 1
    ERR_Fizz = 2 ^ 2
    ERR_Buzz = 2 ^ 3
    ERR_Something = 2 ^ 4
    ERR_SomethingElse = 2 ^ 5
    ERR_AnotherThing = 2 ^ 6
    ERR_SomethingWrong = 2 ^ 7
    '...
End Enum
```

And then if you get `274` and need to know if that contains `ERR_Something` you can do this:

```
If HasFlag(Err.Number, ERR_Something) Then
   ' handle ERR_Something
End If
If HasFlag(Err.Number, ERR_Bar) Then
   ' handle ERR_Bar
End If
```

Or whatever rocks your boat / suits your needs. You could make a function that iterates all the possible error codes, and returns an array or collection with all the codes for which `HasFlag` returns `True`.

---

Note: custom error codes should be added to `vbObjectError` to make sure you're not shadowing/overlapping the built-in error numbers, which could be quite confusing. So, if you intend to use them with `Err.Raise`, I'd suggest you do `Err.Raise vbObjectError + theCustomErrorCode`, and subtract `vbObjectError` from the error code when checking its flags. That way when you get error 13 you know it's a *type mismatch*, not a custom-flag error.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub errDecode()

    Dim errCode As Integer:   errCode = 13
    Dim errText As Variant:   errText = Array("error0", "error1", "error2", "error3", "error4", "error5", "error6", "error7")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 7 To 0 Step -1
        If (errCode And (2 ^ i)) > 0 Then Debug.Print errText(i),
    Next i

    Debug.Print

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for this. Based on your example I came up with the following function that works form me. All error codes are now placed into an array AppErrCodes

```
Public Function AppErrCodes(lngRetCode As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lngResult As Long
    Dim lngReduce As Long
    Dim lngTempResult() As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    lngReduce = 50 'increase this number when > 50 error codes are expected
    While lngRetCode > 0
        lngResult = 2 ^ lngReduce
        lngReduce = lngReduce - 1
        If lngRetCode \ lngResult > 0 Then
            lngRetCode = lngRetCode - lngResult
            'Debug.Print lngResult
            If lngResult > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve lngTempResult(i)
                lngTempResult(i) = lngResult
                i = i + 1
                'Debug.Print lngTempResult(i)
            End If
        End If
    Wend
    AppErrCodes = lngTempResult
End Function
```

Comment: Long data type works with 2^32 values max. If you need 50 or more, use Double.

Comment: @art - what Sergey says is true, `2^50` is too big for a long. Probably you should make a check before entering the while loop.